# Python Dictionaries : Using Tuple as a key, getting error 'unhashale type : list'

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples

So I'm using a dictionary where the key is a set of two integers, and the value of each key is one integer, defined below:

```
for line in f:
    l = line.split(':')
    m = float(l[0])
    c = float(l[1])
    lines[m] = [c]
    lineIndices[(m,c)] = i
    i += 1
```

So, m and c are make the key tuple, and i is the value for a tuple.

When I try retrieving the value of 'i' by using m & c, I get an error.

```
def getIndex(m):
    c = lines[m]
    i = lineIndices.get((m,c))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, as I am using a tuple, not a list. Also, the error only occurs while trying to get the value by key, not while defining the value. Any ideas?

Comment: Calling it with an integer. Something like this -> i = getIndex(m)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some lines from the code you quoted:

```
lines[m] = [c]
```

This assigns a list containing just your float `c` to  `lines[m]`

```
c = lines[m]
```

This assigns that list to `c`. Those two steps are like

```
c = [ c ]
```

Now, in

```
i = lineIndices.get((m,c))
```

Part of the key is now a single-element list. But lists are unhashable, hence the error.

Presumably the first assignment should be

```
lines[m] = c
```